# Will I be blocking the IP of some google related service?

Tags: googlebot

In my sites I have created a script that sends me an email every time a new ip claiming to be google visits the site.

When I see the email I go to check (for example on whois.com) if the ip that claims to be google is really google, and if not, I block it with the firewall.

Normally I find one or two fake googles a week, but in the last few days google has been igniting my server.

```
 103432 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.130 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
1022802 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.80 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
1063366 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
1178083 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.127 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

(number of google accesses on my server in the last 24 hours)

Something is happening and google is entering my server much more than usual and along with the google accesses, the "fake google" has increased a lot. But it is strange that they have increased together...

Will I be blocking the IP of some google service?

(These are those of the last 24 hours)

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='193.203.11.230' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.80.104.189' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.148.124.171' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='37.44.196.194' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='88.218.45.98' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='46.161.60.168' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='212.60.21.63' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='85.202.195.178' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.148.124.139' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='84.54.58.80' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.148.234.198' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='212.119.46.111' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='195.133.24.218' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='83.142.55.37' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='194.87.112.182' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='193.93.195.206' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='194.156.125.92' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='212.119.46.82' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.140.206.107' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='45.66.208.145' reject"
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

they seem to come almost all from the same sources (usually whois.com results are different from each other).

So the doubt comes, am I blocking something that is part of google? Like lighthouse, pagespeed or something else that is still part of the google scans? Or are they just the ip of scammers who pretend to be google to hack my server or clone my sites?

Could it be that google related services claim to be google in the HTTP_USER_AGENT, and then there is nothing about google by verifying domain ownership on whois.com?
(Even if google itself says that the only way to actually verify that an ip belongs to them is to verify its ownership, for example with a reverse dns?)

Can you help me understand who they are, and what should I do with these IPs?

Thanks